# Can Windows API be integrated with scratch HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am creating an HTML widget for my company and would like to integrate the Outlook mailing platform in order to solely **send** emails to associates around the office. However, the widget I am creating can only use HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Is it possible to integrate the Windows Outlook Mail API just to send emails? The documentation uses POST methods to send standard JSON to communicate with the API, but is it possible to use handy JS methods (such as JSON.parse(); and JSON.stringify();) to make this service available in my widget that can only have HTML, CSS, and JS? Any tips/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where will the widget run?

Comment: @DonovanM I am using a service called WonderSign to upload my widget off of iPads around the office.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial should get you started :)

Comment: Thank you so much:)